# llama model to get answers of the questions which are in the context of pdf

Tags: python, machine-learning, pdf, artificial-intelligence, llama

model name = llama-2-7b-chat.ggmlv3.q2_K.bin
pdf-name =  fastfacts-what-is-climate-change.pdf
pdf-data = size of pdf is 2 to 3 pages, having info about climate change.

dependencies:

```
from langchain.document_loaders import PyPDFLoader
from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter
from langchain.embeddings import HuggingFaceEmbeddings
from langchain.vectorstores import FAISS
from langchain.llms import CTransformers
from langchain import PromptTemplate
from langchain.chains import RetrievalQA
```

Below code giving the output as I want

```
>> question : who is ms dhoni<br>
>> answer : Not provided in the pdf. Ask something in the context of pdf.
```

```
def offline_mode(user_question)
    loader = PyPDFLoader("/home/kanhatomar/Work/Running/AmityLLmaArabic/Bot/repository/data/fastfacts-what-is-climate-change.pdf")
    docs = loader.load()

    text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(
        chunk_size=500, # 500
        chunk_overlap=50, #100 play with this numbers for better results
    )
    documents = text_splitter.split_documents(docs)


    embeddings = HuggingFaceEmbeddings(
        model_name="sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2",
        model_kwargs={'device': 'cpu'})


    db = FAISS.from_documents(documents, embeddings)
    db.save_local("faiss")

    template = """Use the following pieces of information to answer the user's question and if the question is not relevant to PDF text just say that you don't know, don't try to make up an answer using your knowledge base.
    If you don't know the answer, just say that you don't know, don't try to make up an answer and don't use your knowledge Base for answer, if the question is not related to text input data so please give a I don't know as an answer please do not use your knowledge base, only use input pdf text for answer.
    if the question is not related to input text so please write I don't know in a answer
    Context: {context}
    Question: {question}
    Only return the helpful answer below from document and nothing else.
    Helpful answer:
    """

    llm = CTransformers(model='/home/kanhatomar/Work/Running/AmityLLmaArabic/Bot/repository/model/llama-2-7b-chat.ggmlv3.q2_K.bin',
                        model_type='llama',
                        config={'max_new_tokens': 256, 'temperature': 0})

    embeddings = HuggingFaceEmbeddings(
        model_name="sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2",
        model_kwargs={'device': 'cpu'})
    db = FAISS.load_local("faiss", embeddings)

    retriever = db.as_retriever(search_kwargs={'k': 2})
    prompt = PromptTemplate(
        template=template,
        input_variables=['context', 'question'])
    qa_llm = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(llm=llm,
                                        chain_type='stuff',
                                        retriever=retriever,
                                        return_source_documents=True,
                                        chain_type_kwargs={'prompt': prompt})


    original_prompt = user_question

    # Tokenize the prompt
    from transformers import AutoTokenizer
    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2")
    tokenized_prompt = tokenizer.encode(original_prompt, return_tensors="pt")

    # Convert tokenized prompt back to string for printing
    tokenized_prompt_str = tokenizer.decode(tokenized_prompt[0], skip_special_tokens=True)

    # print(f"Tokenized prompt: {tokenized_prompt_str}")

    # Retrieve the answer using the QA model
    output = qa_llm({'query': tokenized_prompt_str})
    res = output["result"]
    return {"response": res}
```

Now the code which giving the wrong answer

```
>> question: who is ms dhoni<br>
>> answer: Mahendra Singh Dhoni is an Indian professional cricketer, who plays as a wicket-keeper-batsman. Widely regarded as one of the world's greatest ...
```

```
def offline_mode(user_question):
    try:
        loader = PyPDFLoader("/data/fastfacts-what-is-climate-change.pdf")
        docs = loader.load()

        text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(
            chunk_size=500, # 500
            chunk_overlap=50, #100 play with this numbers for better results
        )
        documents = text_splitter.split_documents(docs)


        embeddings = HuggingFaceEmbeddings(
            model_name="sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2",
            model_kwargs={'device': 'cpu'})


        db = FAISS.from_documents(documents, embeddings)
        db.save_local("faiss")

        template = """Use the following pieces of information to answer the user's question and if the question is not relevant to PDF text just say that you don't know, don't try to make up an answer using your knowledge base.
        If you don't know the answer, just say that you don't know, don't try to make up an answer and don't use your knowledge Base for answer, if the question is not related to text input data so please give a I don't know as an answer please do not use your knowledge base, only use input pdf text for answer.
        if the question is not related to input text so please write I don't know in a answer
        Context: {context}
        Question: {question}
        Only return the helpful answer below from document and nothing else.
        Helpful answer:
        """

        llm = CTransformers(model='/model/llama-2-7b-chat.ggmlv3.q2_K.bin',
                            model_type='llama',
                            config={'max_new_tokens': 256, 'temperature': 0})

        embeddings = HuggingFaceEmbeddings(
            model_name="sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2",
            model_kwargs={'device': 'cpu'})
        db = FAISS.load_local("faiss", embeddings)

        retriever = db.as_retriever(search_kwargs={'k': 2})
        prompt = PromptTemplate(
            template=template,
            input_variables=['context', 'question'])
        qa_llm = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(llm=llm,
                                            chain_type='stuff',
                                            retriever=retriever,
                                            return_source_documents=True,
                                            chain_type_kwargs={'prompt': prompt})


        original_prompt = user_question

        # Tokenize the prompt
        from transformers import AutoTokenizer
        tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2")
        tokenized_prompt = tokenizer.encode(original_prompt, return_tensors="pt")

        # Convert tokenized prompt back to string for printing
        tokenized_prompt_str = tokenizer.decode(tokenized_prompt[0], skip_special_tokens=True)

        # print(f"Tokenized prompt: {tokenized_prompt_str}")

        # Retrieve the answer using the QA model
        output = qa_llm({'query': tokenized_prompt_str})
        res = output["result"]
        return {"response" : res}


    except Exception as e: 
        print(e)
        return {"response": "Something went wrong"}
```

**Notice- Only difference is in try except**
One thing I also noticed that when it gives right answer means don't know for the question which are not in the context of pdf, it runs fast and doesn't use any tokens but when it generate answer of the question which are not in the pdf it uses some tokens and also take more time.

```
This are the tokens
Number of tokens (513) exceeded maximum context length (512).
Number of tokens (514) exceeded maximum context length (512).
Number of tokens (515) exceeded maximum context length (512).
Number of tokens (516) exceeded maximum context length (512).
Number of tokens (517) exceeded maximum context length (512).
Number of tokens (518) exceeded maximum context length (512).
Number of tokens (519) exceeded maximum context length (512).
this 519 in last line is goes to 703
```